# Subscript a std::list

Tags: c++

I have these typedefs:

```
typedef pair<k2Base, list<v2Base>> shuffled_pair;
typedef list<shuffled_pair> shuffled_list;
```

and this function:

```
shuffled_pair getItem(unsigned int index){
    return this->_items[index];
}
```

where `this->_items` is of type `shuffled_list` as declared in the typedef.

I get this error from the compiler:

```
 Type 'const shuffled_list' (aka 'const list<pair<k2Base, list<v2Base> > >') does not provide a subscript operator
```

But the type is basically a list type, so what is the problem?

Comment: If you downvote please explain why and not just downvote. I can edit my question if it is needed, but not if I do not know the problem with it.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem as required please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The question is specific enough. The word "typedef" in the title threw me for a loop at first. I'll remove it.

Comment: What do you mean example? I am trying to get an element from a list, using an index. I show you the compile error that I get trying to do that. rather than that what else can be shown? thanks.

Comment: _@Eyzuky_ Read the link first. Though @potatoswatter gor it right already.

Comment: @Potatoswatter thanks, I thought the typedef has something to do with the problem, sorry for the confusion

Comment: It can never be repeated often enough: NEVER use std::list unless you actually know that a linked list is the right data structure. It is almost never the right data structure. Also, std::list doesn't implement `operator[]()` so you're calling a function that doesn't exist (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: Great, thanks for this clarification regarding the list data structure.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition If I understood the problem from the error message I wouldn't ask the question.

Comment: I guess I was expressing surprise that you read a very clear error message yet still couldn't work it out, and didn't simply Google "C++ list does not provide a subscript operator". I've marked this question as a duplicate of one of the top answers that appears when you do Google using those terms.

Comment: The error message refers to the type defined in the typedef. That is why I thought it is related to that. Sorry for being really dumb.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition

Comment: Okay, that makes some sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library only provides the subscript operator when it has O(1) runtime.

For `std::list`, the library requires you to get an iterator and use `std::advance` to acknowledge the performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a `list` is a linked list. For the type of list that you're looking for, you should look into [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or [`deque`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/deque/), which have a constant-time subscript operator. Deque is generally smarter than vector but doesn't interoperate very well with functions that need pointers to sequences of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Because `std::list` doesn't implement `operator[]` for direct access to members. See [std::list docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/).

Because of the way `std::list` is implemented, this would be an `O(n)` operation. Try using `std::vector` or `std::deque` if you need direct member access.